# Adjusting image description bar of resizable image with CSS

Tags: jquery, html, image, css, resize

I need a responsive image which resizes itself into the maximum of a given area. That works just fine with the code below. But I also need to show a description of the image at the bottom of the image. I want this description bar to fill just bottom of the image and to be animated from the bottom up when I hover on the image.

I'm adding a picture of what I want to achieve for better understanding. I think that placing and sizing of the description bar should be possible using just HTML and CSS but I don't know how.
[GOAL DESCRIPTION](https://en.webshare.cz/file/5284R02nd7/problem-jpg)

I suppose that for the animation of the description bar I need to use some JavaScript animation but it would be great if someone knew a solution with some CSS animation transform trick.

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
.description {
  border: #093 medium solid;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
}
.imageContainer {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="imageContainer">

  <img src="..">

  <div class="description">
    inserted description
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to update your code this way.

```css
html,
body {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 font-size: 0;
}

img {
 max-width: 100%;
 max-height: 100%;
}

.imageContainer {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 position: relative; 
 overflow: hidden;
 display: inline;
}

.description {
 width: 100%;
 height: 0px;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0px;
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
 font-size: 16px;

 -ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
 filter: alpha(opacity=0);
 opacity: 0;
 -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out 0.5s;
 -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out 0.5s;
 -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out 0.5s;
 -ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out 0.5s;
 transition: all 1s ease-in-out 0.5s;
}

img:hover~.description {
 height: 40px;
 -ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
 filter: alpha(opacity=100);
 opacity: 1;
 -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
 -moz-transition-delay: 0s;
 -o-transition-delay: 0s;
 -ms-transition-delay: 0s;
 transition-delay: 0s;
}
```

```html
<div class="imageContainer">
 <img src="http://p1.pichost.me/i/9/1321574.jpg">
 <div class="description" style="color: gray">
  inserted description
 </div>
</div>
```

`.imageContainer` has its display set to inline, because we want the `.description` to flow over the image only. That's why we have to set `html, body`'s font-size to zero, otherwise `.description` will overflow the image a bit.

Comment: Can you somehow align and expand the image from right? When I try for example apply `float:right;` to any tag then the `.description` loses its size and positioning.

Comment: Delete the width property from `.imageContainer` and add `float: right` you mentioned to `img` and `.imageContainer`, that should do the trick.

Comment: Yes, the image is scaling but the bar is not and is pinned to bottom of screen not bottom of image... :(

Comment: Delete also the height property from `.imageContainer`.